# Find the direction of a language using its locale identifier?

Tags: php, internationalization

Does ICU (php Intl extension) provides a way to detect the direction of a language (rtl/ltr) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extending the answer of @MatTheCat, the direction of language can be detected by the locale identifier. Using the [cosmopolitan](https://github.com/salarmehr/cosmopolitan) package it could be as simple as below.

```
<?php
require __DIR__. "/vendor/autoload.php";
use Salarmehr\Cosmopolitan\Cosmo;

echo Cosmo::create('fa')->direction(); // rlt
echo Cosmo::create('en')->direction(); // ltr
```

Answer (score 1):

Direction is a script data. A language can use many scripts and a script can be used by many languages, so I'm not sure you can map a language to a direction.

Even if you could, PHP provides no way to get these informations. However you can try [icanboogie/cldr](https://github.com/ICanBoogie/CLDR) to see if CLDR data would be of any use (after all most languages use only one script).

---

You can find [here](http://unicode.org/repos/cldr/trunk/common/supplemental/supplementalData.xml) a mapping between languages and scripts and [here](http://www.unicode.org/repos/cldr/trunk/common/properties/scriptMetadata.txt) scripts data which include direction.